# My Apache Reverse Proxy is not returning the correct URL when using ProxyPass

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

I have the following configuration which always returns the URL as "https:\sysaid.external.comlogin.jsp" with no "/" between the "https://sysaid.external.com" and the "login.jsp".

```
#REDIRECT for http://sysaid.external.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sysaid.external.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        Redirect / https://sysaid.external.com
</VirtualHost>

#https://sysaid.external.com
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@external.com
        ServerName sysaid.external.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /usr/local/etc/apache22/ssl/webmail.external.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/ssl/webmail.external.com.key
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://srv-01.internal.local:80/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://srv-01.internal.local:80/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://sysaid.external.com:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

Although this one works fine without the SSL redirect...

```
#http://sysaid.external.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@external.com
    ServerName sysaid.external.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://srv-01.internal.local:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://srv-01.internal.local:80/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have others that I redirect with SSL and they all work with no problem.

Testing from telnet to the web server from the proxy server I get the following:

```
root@core-rp-01:/home/user # telnet srv-01.internal.local 80
Trying 172.34.0.10...
Connected to srv-01.internal.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: sysaid.external.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F5FA5C04242A51536916C688A23077F1; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://sysaid.external.com/Login.jsp
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 15:16:06 GMT
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
#REDIRECT for http://sysaid.external.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sysaid.external.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        Redirect / https://sysaid.external.com
</VirtualHost>

#https://sysaid.external.com
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@external.com
        ServerName sysaid.external.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /usr/local/etc/apache22/ssl/webmail.external.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/ssl/webmail.external.com.key
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://srv-01.internal.local/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://srv-01.internal.local/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://sysaid.external.com/
</VirtualHost>
```